# Editing the body tags on specific Joomla articles

Tags: joomla3.0

I need to add Call tracking for a Marketing campaign on my site that is currently housed in Joomla. It requires a certain script to be added inside the `<body>` tag only on designated pages.

I know I can add the script tag to the template but that would make it apply to every page. I am still new to Joomla, so can you tell me if there's a way to apply the script below to only the pages we want to track calls from? It needs to go before the `</body>` tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.callrail.com/companies/808848127/e001797b95eaf41026e7/12/swap.js"></script>
```

Comment: This question is also posted to JSE at: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/17818/120

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to add a script to selected pages is to use an extension such as the professional version of the [EasyScript](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/easyscript) plugin, the [Flexi Custom Code](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/flexi-custom-code) module or similar.

It looks like you could also do this with [Blank Module](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/blank-module) which is free. Publish the module to a non-display module position such as "debug" or similar and enable the module only on the required pages by selecting these under the Menu Assignment tab.

Comment: Thank you, Neil. I actually installed the Blank Module module and that worked, but then I realized I was putting my script tag in the wrong place (I'm new to call tracking) - it needs to go before the </body> tag. Do you know of a module that allows me to select which places to place it at the end of the page?

Comment: Search the Joomla Extensions Directory at http://extensions.joomla.org to try and find something suitable or you'll maybe have to write your own plugin or add some custom code as per the suggestion at http://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/17819/120