# How can you include Javascript in Joomla-articles with Sourcerer?

Tags: javascript, php, joomla, joomla-extensions

The Sourcerer Joomla-extension allows to add css styling or javascript in the head section of one html page. This works pretty well in Joomla-modules.
When trying to add scripts in Joomla-articles, the scripts load on all pages and at the top of the script-list (before jquery.js), so that the scripts don't work, because they need to be placed after jquery.js.
Is there some workaround to load scripts only on pages within an article is displayed?

```
{source}
<?php
$doc->addStyleSheet( JURI::root( true ).'/path/to/your/file.css' );
$doc->addScript( JURI::root( true ).'/path/to/your/file.js' ); 
?>
{/source}
```

Comment: You will be better off asking this on the [joomla.se] dedicated site.

Comment: The answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/39369622/1983389 might help